# mass create privileges for mysql stored procedures

Tags: mysql, permissions

Is it possible to grant a privilege to a user such that they can execute all stored procs on the server (or even within a single db on that server). Looking at the grant syntax docs (5.5), it says that I have to `grant execute on procedure <dbname>.<procname> to ....` for each and every stored proc. Is there a way to do this less clusily by manipulating the mysql db itself?

Answer (score 1):

```
grant execute on <dbname>.*
```

The word 'procedure' should be left out.

Answer (score 1):

For any user privileges defined against database `mydb` run this:

```
UPDATE mysql.db SET execute_priv='Y' WHERE db = 'mydb';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

First, see if any users are defined in `mysql.db` with

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mysql.db;
```

If none of the users already have database-level privileges, then *give it to them*. If you want to grant every user the ability to run stored procedures against database `mydb`, run this

```
INSERT INTO mysql.db (Host,db,user,Select_priv,Insert_priv,Update_priv
Delete_priv,Create_priv,Drop_priv,Grant_priv,
References_priv,Index_priv,Alter_priv,Create_tmp_table_priv
Lock_tables_priv,Create_view_priv,Show_view_priv,Create_routine_priv
Alter_routine_priv,Execute_priv,Event_priv,Trigger_priv
SELECT Host,'mydb',user,Select_priv,Insert_priv,Update_priv
Delete_priv,Create_priv,Drop_priv,Grant_priv,
References_priv,Index_priv,Alter_priv,Create_tmp_table_priv
Lock_tables_priv,Create_view_priv,Show_view_priv,Create_routine_priv
Alter_routine_priv,'Y',Event_priv,Trigger_priv
FROM mysql.user;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Notice I set :

- Execute_priv to 'Y'
- db to 'mydb'